# IE8 does not support parent document form submission using serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make a Ajax request using following snippet.

During execution in IE8 throws error as "No such interface supported."

Jquery version:1.10.1

```
var parentwindow = window.opener;
    if (flag == true) {
            openerForm.action = '/contactform.do?mode=add';

            $.ajax({
            url: openerForm.action,
            data: "&id="+value+"&"+$(parentwindow.document.forms[0]).serialize(),
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(request,response,XMLHttpRequest) {
                if(response.length > 0) {

                    id = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader("id");

                    url = '/redirectcontactform.do?mode=return';
                    document.forms[0].action = url + "&id="+id;
                    document.forms[0].submit();
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

for more details please refer this screen shots.

Please help to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance..

[image]

Comment: You need "http://" in your URLs.

Comment: its not mandatory in URL

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you don't have the protocol, then your URL points to a relative location to your current page.

Comment: ok. seems to problem. so now i can change this . as url = "/form/form2.do"

Comment: any other possibility to resolve this issues